# Is there a plugin for listing subversion tags in Hudson?

Tags: svn, tags, hudson

In [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) we have a job that deploys a specified subversion tag to a server. This tag is currently entered in a text field, but since that is just a typing mistake waiting to happen, we would like that text field to be replaced by a drop down list with the currently available tags. That is, we would like Hudson to go to <subversion repo url>/tags and fetch all tags found there.

I've searched for a [Hudson plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins) or some other way to accomplish this, with no success. This can't be the first time someone wants this, right? Or would this be considered bad practice for some reason that I can not think of at the moment?

**EDIT**

Someone else *did* have the same idea (only three weeks ago), but there is no posted solution right now: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6682?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

**EDIT 2**

I have now implemented Zachary Young's answer and after a few modifications for our environment it works perfectly.

Our modifications:

We have international content encoded in UTF-8 and I had to add that to join.xsl:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

and to the curl command that uploads the new config:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -X POST --data-binary @$WORKING_DIR/new-config.xml $HUDSON_CONFIG_PATH -u $USER:$PASSWORD
```

That's what I remember at the moment at least.

This is now placed in an external script, but I will put it in a Hudson job to make it possible for the other developers to run it easily.

I urge everyone to **upvote Zachary Young's answer**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 01:**
This is now is part of the [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) that ships with `jenkins/hudson.war`.

In lieu of a Hudson plug-in (I do not know Java), how about some XSL (1.0)?  In the following solution :

1. We get a directory list of tags via `svn list --xml`, saved to svn-list.xml
2. We run a transform to turn svn-list.xml into Hudson's internal schema for a choice drop-down, saved to hudson-list.xml
3. We run another transform to join hudson-list.xml into the job's config.xml based on a specific name for the list we want to update, saved to new-config.xml, and update the Hudson job with the new config

**1. `svn list --xml`**

```
  svn list [path-to-svn-tag-directory] --xml > svn-list.xml
```

**2. Convert SVN list to Hudson list**

```
  xsltproc svn-to-hudson.xsl svn-list.xml > hudson-list.xml
```

*svn-to-hudson.xsl*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/lists/list">
    <hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
      <name>[Your Name for the List]</name>
      <description/>
      <choices class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
        <a class="string-array">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
        </a>
      </choices>
    </hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <string>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </string>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**3. Join Hudson List with Job's config.xml**

The following uses `curl` to get fetch the old config.xml, and to post the new one, utilizing Hudson's job API for modifying the config.

```
curl -o old-config.xml http://[your-hudson-server]/job/[job-name]/config.xml -u [username]:[password]
xsltproc join.xsl old-config.xml > new-config.xml
curl -X POST -d @new-config.xml http://[your-hudson-server]/job/[job-name]/config.xml -u [username]:[password]
```

join.xsl requires the presence of hudson-list.xml in the same directory:

```
<xsl:variable name="tag-list" select="document('hudson-list.xml')"/>
```

You will also need to modify

```
<xsl:variable name="list-name" select="string('Name')"/>
```

to the name of your list in the job (e.g., 'SVN tags', 'Tagged Builds', etc...).

*join.xsl*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="tag-list" select="document('hudson-list.xml')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="list-name" select="string('Name')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name = $list-name"> <!-- If the name matches, swap in new list -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$tag-list"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>                      <!-- If the name does not match, copy what's already there -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this end-to-end solution works for you.

Thank you,
Zachary

Comment: Wow, impressive answer! This looks good, but I am missing how this will be run from Hudson. What I mean is: when a Hudson user navigates to the deploy job, I'd like the list of tags to be there already, with no need for the user to run your code.

Do you mean that I should put it in another Hudson job, that is run automatically? That would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes, this could be run as a job in Hudson at regular intervals.  This could also be implemented as a post-commit hook script in SVN which would only run when a new tag was created.  Thank you.

Comment: I now have implemented your solution and it works great. See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [batch task Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Batch+Task+Plugin). This will allow you to go to any build in Hudson (current and old one) and run a batch on that build. The batches are predefined tasks.

This will only work for your purpose if Hudson is creating you official build and tagging it in subversion. And of course only for the builds that are not deleted yet. ;)

Comment: At the moment we are tagging our builds manually, but I'll take a look on that plugin anyway.

Comment: I don't see exactly how I could use that plugin, but I am a Hudson newbie. Do you have a specific solution in mind?

Comment: If hudson is your build authority (which means hudson builds your project and creates the Hudson tag), than you can use either the archived artifacts (since they are the same than what's in subversion) or archive/generate the SVN tag and run your deployment. After installing the plugin, you can create batch tasks for your build job and when you decide later to actually deploy, you can call these tasks manually for a given build.

Comment: What I don't see right now is how that will help me create a select box with the available tags in my Hudson deploy job. Could you expand a little on that? Ahhhh, you mean I should skip that approach and call the automatically created tasks instead (one for each tag)? Hmm, I will consider that.

Comment: You won't have a select box. You just choose a build from the build history and will find a link on the left side task. You Choose your deploy task and you are done. No need to enter any values.